# How can I implement more languages support in Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I want to use Monaco Editor for a personal project , but I saw that it just come with default support for html/css/javascript

I want it to have support for more languages like Java or Python

I could not find any clear tutorial on how to implement this so if anyone did this already or have some idea of how to do it I would appreciate a help

Comment: Please only use language tags if the question is about code written in that language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Monaco comes with basic colorization for Java and Python (along with a bunch of other languages).  If you are interested in writing your own language service for a particular language, [this playground example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages) should give you more than enough to get a prototype working.

If you want custom syntax highlighting for some language, monaco allows this using a related library, [monarch](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) which allows you to specify the highlighter using JSON.

Since your question is a bit vague, you should clarify what you are trying to do in your project. If you are looking to replicate the functionality provided by vscode and a proper language server extension (for example, [vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java)), you'd need to implement a custom language server for your application (link provided in the first paragraph) which is surprisingly easy due to the nice API provided by monaco, but it is still not a trivial task.

On the other hand, if all you want is syntax highlighting/coloring for language A, B, etc., either take advantage of the ones provided by monaco or look into a third-party or custom monarch highlighter.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the response. I wanted to understand more regarding Monarch provided by Monaco. Is it only used for syntax highlighting and coloring ? What else can I achieve with it, I am fairly new with Regex and I am not able to understand what the monarch examples are actually doing. Thanks in advance!